# Text data extraction between keywords in a string

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, nlp, data-science, data-cleaning

I have text data that looks like the following after extracting from a file and cleaning. I want to put the data into a `pandas` dataframe where the columns are `('EXAMINATION', 'TECHNIQUE', 'COMPARISON', 'FINDINGS', 'IMPRESSION')`, and each cell in each row contains the extracted data related to the column name (i.e. the keyword).

> 'FINAL REPORT EXAMINATION: CHEST PA AND LAT INDICATION: F with new onset ascites eval for infection TECHNIQUE: Chest PA and lateral COMPARISON: None FINDINGS: There is no focal consolidation pleural effusion or pneumothorax Bilateral nodular opacities that most likely represent nipple shadows The cardiomediastinal silhouette is normal Clips project over the left lung potentially within the breast The imaged upper abdomen is unremarkable Chronic deformity of the posterior left sixth and seventh ribs are noted IMPRESSION: No acute cardiopulmonary process'

For example, under the column `TECHNIQUE` there should be a cell containing "Chest PA and lateral", and under the column `IMPRESSION`, there should be a cell containing "No acute cardiopulmonary process".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as follows, please note the following assumptions:

1. Keywords as presented are located in that order within the sample text.
2. The keywords are not contained within the text to be extracted.
3. Each keyword is followed by a ": " (the colon and whitespace is removed).

### Solution

```py
import pandas as pd

sample = "FINAL REPORT EXAMINATION: CHEST PA AND LAT INDICATION: F with new onset ascites eval for infection TECHNIQUE: Chest PA and lateral COMPARISON: None FINDINGS: There is no focal consolidation pleural effusion or pneumothorax Bilateral nodular opacities that most likely represent nipple shadows The cardiomediastinal silhouette is normal Clips project over the left lung potentially within the breast The imaged upper abdomen is unremarkable Chronic deformity of the posterior left sixth and seventh ribs are noted IMPRESSION: No acute cardiopulmonary process"

keywords = ["EXAMINATION", "TECHNIQUE", "COMPARISON", "FINDINGS", "IMPRESSION"]


# Create function to extract text between each of the keywords
def extract_text_using_keywords(clean_text, keyword_list):
    extracted_texts = []
    for prev_kw, current_kw in zip(keyword_list, keyword_list[1:]):
        prev_kw_index = clean_text.index(prev_kw)
        current_kw_index = clean_text.index(current_kw)
        extracted_texts.append(clean_text[prev_kw_index + len(prev_kw) + 2:current_kw_index])
        # Extract the text after the final keyword in keyword_list (i.e. "IMPRESSION")
        if current_kw == keyword_list[-1]:
            extracted_texts.append(clean_text[current_kw_index + len(current_kw) + 2:len(clean_text)])
    return extracted_texts


# Extract text
result = extract_text_using_keywords(sample, keywords)
# Create pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([result], columns=keywords)

print(df)

# To append future results to the end of the pandas df you can use
# df.loc[len(df)] = result
```

### Output

```
   EXAMINATION                                        TECHNIQUE                  COMPARISON    FINDINGS                                           IMPRESSION
0  CHEST PA AND LAT INDICATION: F with new onset ...  Chest PA and lateral       None          There is no focal consolidation pleural effusi...  No acute cardiopulmonary process
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the input is organized such that `EXAMINATION`, `TECHNIQUE`, etc. occur in that order.

One approach is to iterate over pairs of strings and use `.split()` to select content between them. Here is one approach:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = 'FINAL REPORT EXAMINATION: CHEST PA AND LAT INDICATION: F with new onset ascites eval for infection TECHNIQUE: Chest PA and lateral COMPARISON: None FINDINGS: There is no focal consolidation pleural effusion or pneumothorax Bilateral nodular opacities that most likely represent nipple shadows The cardiomediastinal silhouette is normal Clips project over the left lung potentially within the breast The imaged upper abdomen is unremarkable Chronic deformity of the posterior left sixth and seventh ribs are noted IMPRESSION: No acute cardiopulmonary process'

strings = ('EXAMINATION','TECHNIQUE', 'COMPARISON','FINDINGS', 'IMPRESSION', '')
out = {}

for s1, s2 in zip(strings, strings[1:]):
    if not s2:
        text = data.split(s1)[1]
    else:
        text = data.split(s1)[1].split(s2)[0]
    out[s1] = [text]

print(pd.DataFrame(out))
```

Which results in:

```
                                         EXAMINATION                TECHNIQUE COMPARISON                                           FINDINGS                          IMPRESSION
0  : CHEST PA AND LAT INDICATION: F with new onse...  : Chest PA and lateral     : None   : There is no focal consolidation pleural effu...  : No acute cardiopulmonary process
```

Comment: The answer as it stands misses the `IMPRESSION` data from the example provided

Comment: Good point. There are a few ways to handle the last word. I updated the answer with one example.

Comment: @KyleFHartzenberg You are right. I believe the problem with the loop, what do you think.